# Convert placeholder to constant in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training neural networks in TensorFlow for use in a Java application. The graphs are written to a pb file using `freeze_graph.py`.

However, there are a number of placeholders in the graph that are used to hold dropout layer keep probabilities. I would like to convert these to constants (=1.0) when writing the graph, as then I don't need to worry about feeding these values when using the network in the Java application.

Is it possible to convert a placeholder into a constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing closer to what you want is a [`placeholder_with_default`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder_with_default). It is a placeholder that takes a default value when not fed.

You can either feed it with the value you want, or just forget about it and let it take the value you specified as a default.

Comment: The updated link to doc - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/placeholder_with_default